# When does the Mac App Store produce notifications?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, notifications

According to [Apple's page on Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#appstore), the Mac App Store is supposed to send you notifications:

> #### Mac App Store notifications
>
> The Mac App Store notifies you when
> updates are available for OS X or purchased apps.

This doesn't seem to be the case for me, as I have now opened the App Store twice to find updates (one for Day One, another to Xcode), having never received a notification for either. Does the App Store only notify about OS X updates, does this feature not actually function, or am I missing something?

Comment: I just realized I have an update for Xcode as well, but I didn't receive any notifications. I checked in Notification Center prefs, the App Store doesn't seem to be in the list.

Comment: Yeah, as I was asking the question, I thought "oh, of course - I just never turned notifications on for the App Store." But no such preference exists!

Comment: Just did some search and found this thread over at MacRumors: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1406156 that says you need to turn on Software Update checks automatically and have it download and *notify* when it is ready to be installed. I guess that's where the notifications will then come in.

Comment: I've got those options turned on, to no avail. Hopefully it's not the case that the Mac App Store app must constantly be *open* to produce notifications... but that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When new updates are available on the Mac App Store, it doesn’t notify you at first. It waits “for a while” and then downloads them in the background. This includes ALL updates. System updates, app updates, all of them. When the download is complete and ready to be installed, that’s when it notifies you.

Comment: This just happened today with another update to Day One and to my printer software. Looks like the problem was, I'm impatient. :)

Comment: See what I told you? :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to have it set to "Automatically download system updates" in the software update panel of system preferences. I got a notification about the xcode update today.